# Oracle SQL: Getting text between two sentences

Tags: oracle, substring

I am trying to extract a set of strings from within a string which is stored in a table column named 'myColumn', one row of that looks like this-

```
Type:MOBILE
Service:GSM
Pd to LOOK:
NOKIA/HMD;
APPLE;
MI;

Pd to SEE (swap):
SAMSUNG;
VIVO;

Pd to SEE (extra):
MOKA;

Contact me: 123456
```

The code I have tried for getting one column is -

```
SELECT regexp_substr(myColumn, '\"Products to be CEASED:"([^"Products to be PROVIDED (swap):"]+)\}', 1,1,NULL,1) AS output FROM mytable
```

I need a query that would return text in between the sentences -

'Pd to LOOK:' and 'Pd to SEE (swap):'

'Pd to SEE (swap):' and 'Pd to SEE (extra):'

'Pd to SEE (extra):' and 'Contact me: 123456'

For Example -

```
Pd to LOOK:            Pd to SEE (swap):  Pd to SEE (extra):
NOKIA/HMD; APPLE; MI;  SAMSUNG;VIVO;      MOKA;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A straight solution is to use substr function in conjunction with instr function. Or DBMS_LOB.instr and substr if the datatype of the column is a LOB.

[documentation for dbms_lob.instr](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_lob.htm#i998546)

for example:

```
select 
     substr(
       mycolumn,
       instr(mycolumn,'Pd to LOOK:'), --starting position
       instr(mycolumn,'Pd to SEE (swap):') - instr(mycolumn,'Pd to LOOK:'), --amount to get
       ) as "Pd to LOOK:"
     --, other expressions/columns
from 
     my_table;
```